# Dropshadow from paper-toolbar overlays paper-dialog

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have basic drawer app with a dialog box. When the dialog box opens the dropshadow from the toolbar(I assume) is bleeding over the box.  Is there a fix for this?

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <paper-header-panel drawer> </...
     <paper-header-panel main> 
       <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-dialog>...</paper-dialog>
        </paper-toolbar> 
      </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
```

[image]

Some things I have tried includes moving the dialog out of the toolbar and set a fixed position. Still if it crosses over the toolbar/header the drop shadow overlays it.

Comment: if you want a drop down menu, you should try paper-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the paper-dialog element outside the paper-toolbar but inside the paper-header-panel?

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
  <paper-header-panel drawer> </...
  <paper-header-panel main> 
    <paper-toolbar>
    </paper-toolbar> 
    <paper-dialog>...</paper-dialog>
  </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```